# How to detect what is starting malicious processes on my server?

Tags: ubuntu, malware

I recently noticed an exceptionally high outbound bandwidth from my Ubuntu 22.04 server. I saw a process with a random name (something like `sdfgardfh`) with a high CPU usage, and suspected that it caused the bandwidth overage. I killed the process, but immediately afterwards, a new similar process started, with a different random name (something like `ktsdfyhr`). I rebooted the server, but immediately after the reboot, I saw a third process with a different random name (something like `fkjytedb`). I suspect some malicious code is running on my server. How can I debug this?

Comment: Have you scanned with clamav or chkrootkit? [https://www.chkrootkit.org]